# Moving objects away from 3D cursor equally like scale, without actually scaling

Tags: modeling

Basically I want to move all selected objects away from the 3D cursor equally, the same way they would move if I scaled them, except i want them to not actually change size at all.

Answer (score 14):

Turn on *Center Only* option in the *3D View* header button with three dots.

[image]

For 2.8+ this toggle can be found inside the *Pivot Point* popover at the top of the 3D View header.

Comment: Duarte's answer is the better one. I learn something new about blender every other day, it seems.

Comment: Lost trying  to do this in 2.8

Comment: In Blender 2.8 the option is **Only Origins** under the **Pivot Point** dropdown at the top of the 3D view.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure the objects are selected, and nothing else.

Set the pivot center for scale to '3D Cursor'.

Hit <kbd>S</kbd> to scale, then use the mouse or keyboard to scale all the objects to your chosen scale, e.g. 3.0

The objects will move away from the 3D Cursor, and get larger.

Keeping the objects selected, switch the pivot center to 'Individual Origins'

Once again, hit <kbd>S</kbd> to scale, then use the mouse or keyboard to scale all the objects to the *reciprocal* of your chosen scale, e.g. 0.33333 (1 divided by 3.0)

Answer (score 1):

The following ugly hack will totally work:

Create an empty for each object, and give each object a copy location constraint to follow that empty. Then parent all the empties to another empty and scale it. It makes a mockery of the dependency graph and wastes a lot of time though.

I don't think blender "knows" how to apply scale to just the locations of objects, but if there's another way it probably involves messing with the object data through python...

Comment: Thanks this will help in some instances but yes its way more work and unfortunately wont work for groups of vertices. For vertices i guess there would be a way to do it by making a bone for each group to move, having a main parent bone with intermediate bones going to each point and unchecking inherent scale, and then applying the armature modifier... but damn there must be an easier way