# Material based on pixel coordinate of an image texture

Tags: node-editor

I've got a scene with a landscape built up of blocks, this is actually made up by instancing a lot of objects onto a mesh.

What I'd like to do is use an image to give each block a specific color without having to apply/separate everything and create and apply materials for each colour.

The image will be like an aerial view with rivers, roads, grass colours, and the blocks will be coloured so together, they look like the image

eg, using this texture:

[image]

would be used to give the blocks colours:

[image]

Comment: I think this is exactly what you're looking for https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=05HFa3jNBH0

Comment: @Gorgious you think correctly! Now I just have to slow down that video and figure out what's going on!

Comment: @JonathanShutt You can slow a youtube video down to 25% of original speed.

Comment: Yeah these videos are more entertaining than educational for newcomers. Basically, project your UVs from view in edit mode while looking at the mesh from the top, then in the UV editor, scale all uv faces to a singular point so each face only has one single flat color associated with it

Comment: There was a similiar question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131607/if-each-cube-here-represents-a-pixel-what-is-the-fastest-way-to-change-its-colo/131638#131638